# Call a function when user leaves current screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I want to call a function or get notified when a user leaves the current screen whether he/she navigates back i.e pop the screen or navigate forward in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a route observer.

First you need to define an observer :

```
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
```

then you need to add the observer to your material app :

```
MaterialApp(
  navigatorObservers: [routeObserver], ...
```

Ok. Now when you create a screen, you can add RouteAware to your state. You will need to subscribe to the observer, and dispose it as well. Therefore you need a stateful widget. Let's say you have a screen called MyScreen, it would look like this :

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> with RouteAware{
  @override


 void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }



 @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  } ...
```

Great! Now you have access to these extra events such as :

```
@override
  void didPopNext() {
    super.didPopNext();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    super.didPush();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    super.didPushNext();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    super.didPop();
  }
```

Let me know if something was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **dispose()** lifecycle function

quote from [API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html)

> **dispose method**
> Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.

for example i'm using it to unsubscribe a **Timer** when user leaves the screen

example:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }
```